# FrameLayout partially gets out of the screen from below in CoordinateLayout

Tags: android

I am new to `CoordinateLayout`. I want my `appBar` to hide when `listView`  in `FrameLayout` scroll up and show again when `listView` scroll down. But there is two problems.

**1"** `FrameLayout` getting out of the screen partially from below.

**2"** AppBar is not scrolling with listView.

**In this below image the blue border is FrameLayout and it is out of screen from below.**

[image]

**Below is `activity_main.xml`;**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#f9f8f8">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**And below is `fragment_main_list.xml` to which I am populating in `FrameLayout` of `activity_main.xml`;**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.nishant.veuz.FragmentMainList">

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/main_progress_bar"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/list_view_main"
        android:dividerHeight="16dp"
        android:divider="@null"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Avoid to use multiple scrollable layouts inside a coordinator layout. Remove the NestedScrollView and use directly your FrameLayout, in alternative keep the NestedScrollView but avoid to put scrollable layouts inside it.

Comment: after removing NestedScrollView listView started to work but now AppBar not scrolling. and listView is partially out of screen from below.

Comment: You're giving listview "match_parent" height, replace Frame Layout with a LinearLayout and give to the listview height="0dp" and layout_weight="1" to make the listview extend to the end of the layout. Add the flag appbar_scrolling_view_behavior to your new LinearLayout

Comment: @NicolaGallazzi above modification is not working. Here the problem is that the FrameLayout which is in activity_main.xml is out of screen, so no matter what we change in listView will not effect FrameLayout.

Comment: before adding `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` the `Framelayout` capture full screen (`appBarLayout` override on it) and after adding `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` the `FrameLayout` slides below `appBar` and parially got out of screen from below.

Comment: Add app:layout_collapseMode="pin" to your toolbar. I this way you'll pin the toolbar to the top of the screen and the frame layout will not override go under the navigation bar. Also remove  app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"

Comment: I got it working by adding         `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"`
 in `listView`. but `nestedScrollingEnabled` only available in API 21 and higher. but minimum API in my application is API 14.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158686/discussion-between-nicola-gallazzi-and-nishant-bhakta).

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your Parent Layout from CoordinatorLayout into LinearLayout, like so

```
...
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#f9f8f8"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"> 
    ...
```

from your `NestedScrollView` try to enclose it with;

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- MAIN CONTENT-->
        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:fillViewport="true"
         app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp" />


        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: But I want my appBar to scroll up and down with listView